# Fluidly resizing all images based on browser window size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm iterating through all my images and displaying them very simply like this:

```
<div class="big-container">
    <!--for every image-->
    <div class="image-container">
        <img class="image" src="url">
    </div>
    <!-- end of iteration -->
</div>
```

With an equally simple css solution:

```
.image-container {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 312px;
    height: auto;

    img.image {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to resize all images fluidly as the user resizes the window. So with every pixel the window is shrinking, the images should all shrink some amount. This is so that when the window is really narrow (as for mobile), the images **won't appear one-by-one down the page, but rather be displayed two-by-two.** Right now they won't resize until the window is literally too small for one image to be displayed.

Is there a way using CSS (`nth-child`?) or JavaScript to achieve this fluidly and without too much strain on the browser? I've heard that the resize checking in browsers isn't what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a set of media queries and do the math, see if it helps. I use the `font-size: 0;` trick on the container to remove the the white space between the inline-blocks.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnxd0yra/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.item {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 312px;
}
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 1248px) { /*312x4*/
  .item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 936px) { /*312x3*/
  .item {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 624px) { /*312x2*/
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 312px) { /*312x1*/
  .item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/200"></div>
</div>
```